# H264 parsing - slice header detection

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, h.264

I know that in h264 we can detect a NAL Unit by the bit pattern `0x000001`.

Is there an equivalent method to detect a slice header in a NAL Unit? How does one handle multi-slice NAL units?

Currently I'm using parsing code for h264 and get the slice header in a respective structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slice header syntax is discussed on page 36 (section 7.3.3) of the [H.264 standard](http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.264-200305-S!!PDF-E&type=items).

It might be worth having a look at the [reference software](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/).

Comment: Thanks Alex!!Its helps a lot.Thanks again.

Comment: @chiv If this has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. [see FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)